# What is a word that could define someone who's good at showing superficial kindness and friendliness towards others?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that could define someone who's good at showing superficial kindness and friendliness towards others but speaks ill of them or gossips about them behind their back ?

Comment: Related: [Is there a word for overly friendly speech from someone who insults you behind your back?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196943/is-there-a-word-for-overly-friendly-speech-from-someone-who-insults-you-behind-y/196956#196956) and [A good noun for a two-faced person](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24216/a-good-noun-for-a-two-faced-person)

Answer (score 1):

[Double-faced](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/double-faced): is a common term used to refer the behaviour you describe: (from TFD)

> - hypocritical; deceitful; two-faced.

Comment: Definitely *two-faced*, but I've never encountered *double-faced* except when dealing with tape!

Comment: Umm, in my culture, "Double-faced" maybe not a good word to describe a people.